# Error validating the contents of a file using regex in C

Tags: c, regex

I am having a problem with the below code validating a file using regex. My file must only contain letters or numbers. My regular expression is:

```
#define to_find "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

which is located in my main.h file. The below code is in my main.c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int ret_val;
    regex_t regex;
    FILE *fp;
    char line[1024];

     if (regcomp(&regex, to_find, REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile regex '%s'\n", to_find);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tree OR tree [filename]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        fp = fopen(strcat(argv[1],".dat"), "r");

        printf("file opened\n");
        while ((fgets(line, 1024, fp)) != NULL)
        {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
            if ((ret_val = regexec(&regex, line, 0, NULL, 0)) != 0);
            {
                printf("Error: %s\n", line);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
        printf("File closed\n");        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My file I am reading is called names.dat and contains:

```
int
char
[
double
```

What is happening is it is kicking out at the very first line which it should kick out at the 3rd line. I am sure this is pretty simple to solve but it seems I have not figured it out. I would appreciate any help. Also, how do I deal with the

```
\n
```

character in the file? this file will have several lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: I think you want to have `REG_NEWLINE`?

Comment: @CarlNorum Why not? To me it seems efficient.

Comment: @thejh There was no change to my error when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: And you don't want to use `grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' file.dat` because...?

Comment: Don't `strcat` onto argv[1] - you're clobbering a bit of memory there.

Comment: Commentors: the problem as described can be solved in lots of different ways (up to an external `grep`). However, you don't know why the OP is attempting to do it this way.

Comment: @tripleee No because I must throw and error AND what line that error occurred on. That portion is not in the code yet.

Comment: See also [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

Comment: Also, beware of lines in C that start with 'if' and end with ';'

Comment: @Clint - compare to `while (((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) if (!isalnum(c)) return -1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some small errors but the one that cause the error is:

```
// Do you see this sweet little semicolon :P ----------------+
if ((ret_val = regexec(&regex, line, 0, NULL, 0)) != 0); // <+
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", line);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

beside this line:

```
fp = fopen(strcat(argv[1],".dat"), "r");
```

You cannot add to `argv`, you need to create a new buffer to hold the data, create a buffer with `PATH_MAX` size add append the path to it. Here an improved version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define to_find "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int ret_val;
    regex_t regex;
    FILE *fp;
    char file[PATH_MAX];
    char line[1024];

     if (regcomp(&regex, to_find, REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile regex '%s'\n", to_find);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tree OR tree [filename]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        sprintf(file, "%s.dat", argv[1]);
        fp = fopen(file, "r");
        if( fp == NULL ) {
            perror("Error");
            return -1;
        }

        printf("file opened\n");
        while (fscanf(fp, "%1023s", line) > 0)
        {
            if ((ret_val = regexec(&regex, line, 0, NULL, 0)) != 0)
            {
                printf("Not match: %s\n", line);
                //return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                printf("Match: %s\n", line);
            }
        }

        regfree(&regex);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File closed\n");        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See the diff: http://www.diffchecker.com/8itbz5dy

test:

```
$ gcc -Wall sample.c 
$ 
$ cat name.dat 
int
char
[
double
$ ./a.out name
file opened
Match: int
Match: char
Not match: [
Match: double
File closed
$
```

Comment: @sjnarv Thanks didn't notice!

Comment: @Sp. What is `%1203s` in the line `while (fscanf(fp, "%1023s", line) > 0)` mean if you do not mind me asking? I have never run into that before.

Comment: @Clint it should limit the length that `scanf` reads up to 1023 character, `line` is 1204 it cannot holds more.